# Possibility of removing two water molecules from glycerol

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, carbonyl-compounds, alcohols, hydrolysis

Not a chemist, but from a chemical formula perspective, how hard would it be to create acetone by acidifying glycerol?

$$\ce{C3H8O3 + 2 H+ <=> C3H6O + 2 H2O}$$

Has anyone ever heard of this being attempted? If it isn't possible, why?

Comment: You do know that charge is conserved? Dehydration of glycerol yields acrolein.

Comment: Patent for forming acrolein by dehydration of glycerol  https://patents.google.com/patent/US8378136B2/en

Comment: Your equation is not valid, because it is not balanced. There are 2 positive charges on the left hand side, and none on the right hand side.

Comment: The chemical formula doesn't tell you much that is useful for judging a reaction's feasibility. You need to look at the structure and plausible reaction mechanisms. In this case, a reaction giving acetone is not remotely likely.

Comment: Thank you. So to balance the equation neutral H2 would need to be substituted for the 2H+. And you point out also that the dehydration of glycerol results in acrolein or propenal in the above patent. A secondary reaction would then be needed to add H2 and produce propanal. How unlikely is the conservation of the C2 oxygen if you remove 2 out of the three from glycerol? I understand that it couldn't exist without H2 addition if you remove two H2O.